# Group by both similar and opposite elements

Tags: c#

I have the following type of data:

```
   Acct    Date     From    To     Amt
1) ABC     today    USD     CAD    100 
2) ABC     today    CAD     USD   -250 
3) DEF     today    GBP     AUD    300 
4) DEF     today    GBP     AUD    200
```

I need to group the data and sum the amounts. To do that I need to net the opposing currencies so that the result should be:

```
   Acct    Date     From    To     Amt
1) ABC     today    CAD     USD   -150 
2) DEF     today    GBP     AUD    500
```

I am using .Net 3.5.
I've only been able to net data that have the same from and to currencies:

```
var net = data.GroupBy(x=> new { x.Acct, x.Date, x.From, x.To})
.Select new {y.Key.Acct, y.Key.Date, y.Key.From, y.Key.To, Net = y.Sum(x => x.Amt)});
```

Is there a way to net both similar and opposing currencies?

Comment: I see something wrong in your example. USD -> CAD is 100, CAD to USD is -250 thus aggregated CAD to USD should be -350 and not -150

Comment: @Tilak It may look off but that's the requirement I have. These are buy and sell transactions that need to be netted.

Comment: Then the question is, why is it USD -> CAD -150, and why not CAD -> USD -150. There has to be more information for grouping. And I am sure that extra information will make it easy

Comment: Positive amts are buy trans and negatives are sells. To determine which way to transact, look at the absolute value of the amt. In the ex above, for line 1, we need to buy 100 units of USD with CAD. On line 2, we need to sell 350 units of CAD with USD. In other words the 2 lines mean we need to buy 100 USD and at the same time we need to sell 250 USD which nets to selling 150 USD total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** Go to the end for an explanation of the second block of code and an important disclaimer in bold.

```
var query = from acct in accts
    select new
    {
        acct.From,
        acct.To,
        acct.Amount,
        FirstOrientedAmount = ((acct.From.CompareTo(acct.To) == -1 && acct.Amount < 0) ||
            (acct.From.CompareTo(acct.To) >= 0 && acct.Amount > 0)) ? acct.Amount : 0,
        SecondOrientedAmount = ((acct.From.CompareTo(acct.To) >= 0 && acct.Amount < 0) ||
            (acct.From.CompareTo(acct.To) == -1 && acct.Amount > 0)) ? acct.Amount * -1 : 0
    } into r
    group r by new
    {
        First = (r.From.CompareTo(r.To) == -1 ? r.From : r.To),
        Second = (r.From.CompareTo(r.To) == -1 ? r.To : r.From)
    } into g
    select new
    {
        First = g.Sum(acctval => acctval.FirstOrientedAmount) + g.Sum(acctval => acctval.SecondOrientedAmount) > 0 ? g.Key.Second : g.Key.First,
        Second = g.Sum(acctval => acctval.FirstOrientedAmount) + g.Sum(acctval => acctval.SecondOrientedAmount) > 0 ? g.Key.First : g.Key.Second,
        FTotal = g.Sum(acctval => acctval.FirstOrientedAmount),
        STotal = g.Sum(acctval => acctval.SecondOrientedAmount),
        Total = g.Sum(acctval => acctval.FirstOrientedAmount) + g.Sum(acctval => acctval.SecondOrientedAmount),
    };
```

This gives:

```
CAD USD -150
GBP AUD 500
```

**EDIT**: I'm leaving up the old code because I don't entirely understand these requirements, but I'm posting something that does not rely on the compiler to optimize it:

```
var query = from p in accts
    select new
    {
        p.From,
        p.To,
        p.Amount,
        OrientedAmount = ((p.From.CompareTo(p.To) == -1 && p.Amount < 0) ||
            (p.From.CompareTo(p.To) >= 0 && p.Amount > 0)) ? p.Amount : p.Amount * -1
    } into r
    group r by new
    {
        First = (r.From.CompareTo(r.To) == -1 ? r.From : r.To),
        Second = (r.From.CompareTo(r.To) == -1 ? r.To : r.From)
    } into g
    select new
    {
        g.Key.First,
        g.Key.Second,
        Total = g.Sum(val => val.OrientedAmount)
    } into last
    select new
    {
        First  = last.Total > 0 ? last.Second : last.First,
        Second = last.Total > 0 ? last.First : last.Second,
        Total = last.Total
    };
```

1. This works by first orienting all amounts toward a transaction whose From account is the biggest lexicographically ordered currency name. You flip the sign on the amount if the current transaction line is in effect moving funds toward the lexicographically smallest currency name.
2. Now group by the accounts in the transaction by ordering them lexicographically.
3. Select the total (so that we only have to do this once). To do this, add all the oriented amounts.
4. If the total value is positive (the way I did it), we have a net value going into the biggest lexicographically ordered currency name. If it is negative, the net value is going into the smallest lexicographically ordered currency name.

**However, I'm not convinced these are good requirements (or I misunderstand the original requirements). If you look at what this problem is solving, it is combining "A B sell", "A B buy", "B A buy", and "B A sell" into one group. "A B 100", in this situation, means "A B -100". The first means buy 100 A. The second means sell 100 B into A. If you look at the way this problem is solved** *they are the same thing.* **But in reality,** *they aren't the same thing.* **Selling 100 B will not give you the same amount of A as buying 100 A will. You need the exchange rate to normalize this.**

Comment: You can read it this way--> #1) buy 100 units of USD; #2) sell 350 units of USD. Therefore, if you have to buy and sell the same currency, why make 2 transactions and pay 2 commisions when you can just get the diff in this case just sell 150 USD. That's the rationale.

Comment: Not if you also select the From and To currencies; in that case you get 3 rows showing USD -> CAD 100 ; CAD -> USD -250 and AUD -> GBP 500

Comment: In fact I tried something similar to this before, where I set a property called currency pair in alphabetical order using String.Compare. The problem is if want to know the currency direction of the final result, ie you add the from and to currencies in the select, you get 3 rows instead of 2 in the result.

Comment: This can also be simplified if you don't want to consider (USD, CAD, sell) to be in the same group as (CAD, USD, sell).. (since, correct me if i'm wrong, selling 100 CAD is not exactly the same as selling 100 USD).

Comment: This satisfies my requirement, although I think it could be a performance drag. Perhaps it could simplified a bit but many many thanks for your effort.

Comment: Can you also give a brief explanation of how it works? Sorry spend too much time looking at this problem.

Comment: Edited with description.